# Multiple ADs with 2 way trust not working in SP Org Browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, organization-browser

We run SP 2010.

We have multiple AD domains in the enterprise due to mergers and acquisitions.  We now have managers and employees under the manager working in different domains.

Is there a solution for this where I can have AD1\User1 and make his manager AD3\Mngr2?

We currently bring all people into User Profiles but the organisational browser cannot display a manager in a different AD to the current profile being used.

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I enabled netbios in sharepoint and now we can see managers in different domains

[TechNet: Configure profile synchronization (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx)

```
$ServiceApps = Get-SPServiceApplication
$UserProfileServiceApp = ""
foreach ($sa in $ServiceApps)
  {if ($sa.DisplayName -eq "<UPSAName>") 
    {$UserProfileServiceApp = $sa}
  }
$UserProfileServiceApp.NetBIOSDomainNamesEnabled = 1
$UserProfileServiceApp.Update()
```

Replace  with the name of the User Profile service application.

Comment: Practical question and good answer. Thank you both!